# Maven dependency not exist for flowable

Tags: java, maven, activiti, flowable

Trying to find the java maven dependency of flowable, I found the maven repository of flowable [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.flowable/flowable-spring-boot-starter-basic)

[image]

When I am trying to search the org.flowable in maven dependency it not showing any.

Comment: well, it's said that the index downloads are disabled, so it could be the case that i cannot contact any repository to index the artifacts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For adding the flowable dependency in maven, only need to add:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.flowable</groupId>
    <artifactId>flowable-spring-boot-starter-rest</artifactId>
    <version>${flowable.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

This will download the dependency of the flowable.

Comment: for flowable version https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.flowable/flowable-spring-boot-starter-basic